# Exception in report with Laravel 5.2 and JasperReports

Tags: jasper-reports, laravel-5, cloud9

I'm getting this error from Laravel 5.2 with JasperReports in cloud9

```
Exception in JasperPHP.php line 178: Your report has an error and couldn't be processed! Try to output the command using the function `output();` and run it manually in the console.
```

This is part of my code

```
 $database = \Config::get('database.connections.mysql');

        $output = public_path() . '/reportes/'.time().'_resumen';

        $ext = "pdf";

        \JasperPHP::process(
            public_path() . '/reportes/resumen.jasper', 
            $output, 
            array($ext),
            array("idVersion"=> $idVersion),
            $database,
            false,
            false
        )->execute();
```

I already change execute to output and this is what I get

```
$command= \JasperPHP::process(
            public_path() . '/reportes/resumen.jasper', 
            $output, 
            array($ext),
            array("idVersion"=> $idVersion),
            $database,
            false,
            false
        )->output();
        echo $command;
        die();
```

This is the call to *jasperstarter* (with some line breaks for readability):

```
/home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/cossou/jasperphp/src/JasperPHP/../JasperStarter/bin/jasperstarter 
process /home/ubuntu/workspace/public/reportes/resumen.jasper 
-o /home/ubuntu/workspace/public/reportes/1467084704resumen 
-f pdf 
-r /home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/cossou/jasperphp/src/JasperPHP/../../../../../ 
-P idVersion=68 -t mysql -u pms1023 -H localhost -n c9 --db-port 3306
```

Comment: You probably need to install JDK. See [this closed issue](https://github.com/cossou/JasperPHP/issues/28)

Comment: I have the JDK already installed and also check that the driver where here vendor/jasperphp/src/JasperStarter/jdbc and nothing

Comment: Well, I suppose *your report has an error*. Did you design it in the Jaspersoft Studio so that you could check the preview?

Comment: Yes, I checked and I saw the report with all the information y Jaspersoft Studio,but when I tried in the web page doesn't work @tobi6

Comment: What happened when you changed it to `output`? Can you call the jasperstarter command without an issue?

Comment: I don't have the error now, we change the template to another one and it seems that it was  resolved. The thing is that it show the report but without any information in it. But in Jaspersoft Studio it show everything  @tobi6